# Deploying app onto AWS Lambda throws Postgres Driver error

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-boot-2

I created a spring-boot2 app and also spun up a POSTGRES DB on AWS. I can connect to it fine when I launch the app locally. However, when I right click on template.yaml and choose Deploy Serverless application, the deployment goes fine. But in the logs I see this error:
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver`
And all my endpoints are returning bad gateway 502.

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=myurl
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

My template.yaml:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 20

Resources:
  EmployeeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: EmployeeTest
      Handler: com.test.LambdaHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java8
      MemorySize: 512
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: any
Outputs:
  EmployeeTestAPI:
    Description: URL for application
    Value: !Sub 'https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Stage/employee'
    Export:
      Name: EmployeeTestAPI
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2</artifactId>
            <version>[1.4,)</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>boot</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>boot</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


</project>
```

Also, when I am not using postgres in any of my endpoints and remove that from my dependencies in pom.xml and remove my application.properties, there is no error and can access my endpoints fine. Why is AWS Lambda not able to pick up the postgres driver?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, replaced the commented out dependency:

```
    <!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```